# joining two arrays within a nested hash

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, push

I'm running a script that counts the contents of a database query and return the result in a hash for more processing.
Unfortunately, what seems to be happening is that the array fills up with arrays rather than them being joined together.

Im not sure what's going on here exactly as when I remove it from the while loop and just define the arrays manually for pushing, they are all pushed into one array under my key as expected.

```
while ( my $data = $query->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    my $value     = decode_json $data->{value};
    my @array = $value->{array};
    my %hash;
    my $person = "Scott";
    push @{$hash{$person}->{"arrays"}}, @array;
}
```

Dumper results in the following:

```
      'scott' => {
                    'arrays' => [
                                [
                                  'stuff1', 'stuff2'
                                ],
                                [
                                  'stuff3','stuff4'
                                ],
                               ]
                   }
```

I expect the array not to become a nest of other arrays, Instead just one array containing the stuff\d values

Comment: Try `my @array = @{ $value->{array} }` instead of `my @array = $value->{array}`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this. I'm not surprised it was something so simple, but I'm still a bit lost here. I'm guessing that wrapping what I thought was an array actually wasn't and it changes the context?

Comment: You are welcome! The issue was that `$value->{array}` is an array reference. If it is assigned to `@array`, it becomes an array of length one, where the first  (and only) element is the reference to `$value->{array}`. However, if you put an `@` in front of the array reference it will unpack it into a real array (not a reference to an array). See [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> my $value     = decode_json $data->{value};
> ```

Here, you're decoding your JSON into a Perl data structure. It's a reference (as we can see by the fact that it's stored in a scalar variable), but we're not yet sure what kind of reference it is.

> ```
> my @array = $value->{array};
> ```

Ok, here we get a clue as to the kind of reference. I guess you expect it to be an array reference as you're trying to store in an array. But you're just storing the reference in the array. If you were to look at the array at this point, it would contain a single element with a value like `ARRAY(0x99999999)`. This is the equivalent of doing:

```
my @array = [ 'list', 'of', 'values' ];
```

Or

```
my @array = \@some_other_array;
```

What I think you actually want is:

```
my @array = @{ $value->{array} };
```

This deferences the array reference and stores the actual elements from the references array in the new array. This is the equivalent of:

```
my @array = ( 'list', 'of', 'values' );
```

Or:

```
my @array = @some_other_array;
```

I hope the difference is clear.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the more in depth explanation Dave!